# Django cascade delete option?

Tags: django, django-models

My model does not cascade delete?

I have a FK in a model called below called 'link' upon deleting product link does not get deleted.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    objects = ContentManager()
    #FK
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link, related_name="content", null=True, blank=True)
```

When I delete product FK remains, why?

**Delete Code:**

```
@login_required
def delete_product(request):
    if request.POST:
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=request.POST['product_id'])
            product.delete()
```

**Link Model:**

```
class Link(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    hits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: You'll need to post more than that : the Link model, your delete code, and some queries showing before and after the state of your db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your foreignkey is in the wrong model and should be in the Link model.

I suspect that if you delete a link instance right now it will delete any associated products

Comment: I need the FK to be in Product, this is required as Link is used by other models such as Image, and RSS

Comment: Am I correct in that deleting a link instance removes the associated product instance? If not then I'll delete this answer

Comment: Yes, it need to be the other way around for this to work you are right, but the model is not wrong. However, Django must have something to force this with my writing a signal

Comment: I guess you could look at model inheritance so you have like 
`class ProductLink(Link):
     models.ForeignKey(Product)`
and do separate ones for Image/RSS

Answer (score 0):

`.delete` method is not invoked when delete in bulk; as Queryset generate the sql statement and execute it directly. So deletion of ForeignKey field not invoked. If you do that, you may need to use `pre_delete` and/or `post_delete` signals.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-delete

Comment: Aha, As I think, you use `One-to-Many` relation, `One` is Link and `Many` is Product. `Many` is deleted when `One` deleted, and `One` of `Many` **DO not** delete the `One`.